# Terraform: Failed to query available provider packages (Azapi)

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I try to use the Azure/Azapi Provider within my Terraform project but after I add the provider and run `terraform init`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azapi: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azapi
```

This is how my providers.tf looks like:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.16.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "=0.4.0"
    }

  }

  required_version = "=1.2.6"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "azapi" {
}
```

When I run `terraform providers`, I can see that the provider has a wrong registry URL within my module:

```
├── module.az-aca-env
│   └── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azapi]
```

I would expect something like **registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I found a workaround. I have to add a `providers.tf` **inside my module** directory (/modules/az-aca-env) with the following content:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "=0.4.0"
    }
  }
}
```

After adding it, the `terraform init` works ✅.

Comment: Yes, because it's not an official Terraform provider.

Comment: Ah, this is the reason. Thank you Marko

Comment: Thanks for the answer! According to the documentation it should not be capitalized https://registry.terraform.io/providers/azure/azapi/latest/docs. And you are correct that the provider block is not needed anymore with the latest terraform versions :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the provider name, it is `Azure/azapi` as per documentation [1]:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "0.4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
  # Configuration options
}
```

You can always see how to use the provider if you click on the big purple button in the top right-hand corner saying `USE PROVIDER`.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/azure/azapi/latest/docs

Comment: Thank you for your help Marko. Unfortunately I still get the same error after changing the provider.

Comment: Have you removed the `.terraform` directory and re-run `terraform init` after changing the provider name?

Comment: yes, I did. I also tried removing the .terraform.lock.hcl

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Hm, when I start from scratch, I am able to run terraform init without any issues. Looks like it has something to do with my modules (I am using a local /modules/az-aca-env module).

Comment: Was there any reference to the provider in the module?

Comment: Here is a minimal sample to reproduce the issue: https://file.io/12CetDObMS0E