# Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azapi (Azure/azapi)

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to create `Application ID URI` of an application registration that is already deployed to Azure and using `azapi` for that as Application ID URI is going to be the app's own application_id (i.e. `api://[app_id]`). So I am trying to accomplish this via `azapi`.

However I get following error when I run `terraform init -upgrade`:

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azapi: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider  
│ named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azapi
│
│ Did you intend to use azure/azapi? If so, you must specify that source address in each module which requires that provider. To see which modules  
│ are currently depending on hashicorp/azapi, run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

I have my `provider.tf` file as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
  azapi = {
    source = "Azure/azapi"
  }
  azuread = {
    source = "hashicorp/azuread"
  }
  azurerm = {
    source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
  }
}
backend "azurerm" {
  #..... #necessary info
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id       = "tenant_id"
}

provider "azapi" {
  subscription_id = "subscription_id"
  tenant_id       = "tenant_id"
}
```

and `main.tf` like so (where `app_reg` is already defined):

```
resource "azapi_update_resource" "update_app_reg" {
type = "Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01"
name = "app-reg"
parent_id = azuread_service_principal.app_reg_service_principal.object_id

# Update Application ID URI
body = jsonencode({
"properties" = {
  "identifierUris" = [
    "api://${azuread_application.app_reg.application_id}"
    ]
  }
})

depends_on = [azuread_application.app_reg]
}
```

when I remove `resource "azapi_update_resource" .........` , `terraform init -upgrade` runs successfully. However when I leave it defined as it is, I get the error above.

I have already defined the provider and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550279/6742553), [microsoft documentation about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/get-started-azapi-update-resource?tabs=azure-cli#implement-the-terraform-code) and [hashicorp documentation about this](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-provider-azapi/blob/005e951538c643af1a995812f170d0a1b7de370c/examples/Microsoft.Web/list_and_update_appsettings/main.tf), but nothing helpful...

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurred because I didn't specify the provider in my module.

So here was my structure:

```
.
├── providers.tf
├── main.tf
├── modules
    ├── main.tf
```

and `resources "azapi_update_resource" ...` was in `modules/main.tf` and `provider "azapi"...` was in `./providers.tf`. After following steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73301796/6742553), I have created a new `providers.tf` inside the `modules` directory and added:

```
terraform {
 required_providers {
  azapi = {
   source = "Azure/azapi"
   }
  }
}
```

And this have resolved the issue.

After I ran the `terraform providers` command, I got this:

```
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/azure/azapi]
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread]
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm]
├── module.application_registrations
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread]
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm]
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azapi]
```

So, there you can see that `module.application_registrations` is referring to `hashicorp/azapi` which is non-existent.

Long story short; adding `providers.tf` into module directory and adding `azapi` into it has resolved the issue!

Comment: The separation of sentences near "after following" is not 100% clear. Can you check it?